# Next page "spacebar button" press

Tags: javascript, file, keycode, location-href

I need the JavaScript to go to 'pag2' when I press spacebar, but it does nothing, there isn't anything on 'pag1' or 'pag2' (the files)
`

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.key == " " ||
      e.code == "Space" ||      
      e.keyCode == 32      
  ) {
    window.location.href="pag2.html"
  }
}
```

`

I've tried changing the href to replace, but it didn't work. You should know what I was expecting, but if you didn't, here's what I was expecting:
It to take me to file 'pag2'

Comment: and I've hooked the file up to each other properly

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It works for me.

Comment: It works fine for me. Check if you miss typed the file name, or maybe there is other code the overrides this?

Comment: @StaticSpaghetti13 I did mistype the file name, I simplified all the file names, like images is imj, I did the file as a .htm, not .html